# Can ArcPublisher 10 publish backwards to an 9.3 PMF?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, mxd

It seems like a lot of other functions within ArcGIS are getting backwards compatibility (file geodb creation, MXD files).  I'll still need to publish 9.3 PMF files for a few months and I couldn't find anything in the Publisher settings that would allow me to publish to a previous version.  Is it possible?

Comment: Yes please! (someone? anyone?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this document](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//006600000253000000.htm) (around halfway down, under the heading **Saving from ArcGIS 10 to ArcGIS 9.2**) you cannot publish a PMF for consumption via ArcGIS 9.2 if you're using ArcGIS 10. It does *not* mention this for 9.3, but if you're having difficulties reading a PMF in 9.3 that was published via 10, then that apparently doesn't work either (despite ESRI's not mentioning it in their documentation).

Their suggested workaround is:

> [S]ave the .mxd file to a previous
>   version and publish it on a machine
>   with an older version of ArcGIS.

Comment: That documentation is unclear! An ArcMap 9.3.1 virtual machine it is then.

Comment: We use publisher 10 to save for 9.3 clients. I'll try and get my colleague who does this to chime in here.

Comment: sorry, I have to retract that. He's using 9.3 in a Virtual Machine. :(